# How to check the relationship between a character and numeric group?

Tags: r, glm, anova

I want to check the effect of a specific numeric variable on a character vector in R.

```
                      A       B       C       D       E    F_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE AJCC_TUMOR_PATHOLOGIC_PT GRADE           PRIMARY_SITE
TCGA.2J.AAB4.01 -0.2527 -1.2093  0.7556 -0.7071 -0.1310                   Stage IIB                       T2    G2 Other (please specify)
TCGA.2J.AAB6.01  1.2080  0.4815 -0.3242 -0.7088  4.0856                   Stage IIA                       T3    G2       Body of Pancreas
TCGA.2J.AAB8.01  0.7529  0.7916  0.0596 -0.5287  1.1315                   Stage IIB                       T3    G3       Head of Pancreas
TCGA.2J.AAB9.01 -0.3248 -0.7941 -0.5940  0.3325 -0.4385                   Stage IIB                       T3    G1       Head of Pancreas
TCGA.2J.AABA.01 -0.4154  0.2808  0.7133 -0.7088 -0.6147                   Stage IIB                       T3    G2       Head of Pancreas
TCGA.2J.AABE.01  0.6566 -0.1300  0.5751 -0.7088 -0.7381                   Stage IIA                       T3    G2       Body of Pancreas
```

As you see, columns `A` to `E` contain numerical values. `F_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE` contains values `Stage I`,  `Stage IA`,  `Stage IB`, `Stage IIA`, `Stage IIB`, `Stage III` and  `Stage IV`.

I want to see the effect of each of the factors `A` to `E` on `F_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE` independently. When I run the following code

```
glm(AJCC_PATHOLOGIC_TUMOR_STAGE ~ A, data = merged.data.frame.Stage, family = "binomial")
```

I get the following error :

`Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1`

I want then use `anova` to get the results. What might be causing the problem and how can I avoid it?